# basic operations on list of list

Tags: python

I am curious on understanding how to multiply values from one list  with two other list but both list being in the same list.

For example,

```
a = [[2, 3, 1, 6], [1, 6, 1, 9], [1,`1, 1,2]]
```

and I want to get:

```
[[2, 18, 1, 54], [2, 3, 1, 12]],[[2, 18, 1, 54], [1, 6, 1, 18]], [[2, 3, 1, 12], [1, 6, 1, 18]]
```

where  a[0] multiplies with the rest of the list  and a[1] multiplies with the other lists and etc.

I have searched online but I don't understand it or there aren't any examples that really look at multiply or lists together in the context of nested lists.

I am  sorry if it doesn't make sense, I am still pretty new with python and english isn't my first language.

Comment: What's the logic to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `numpy.array` and `*` like below:

```
import numpy as np
a = [[2, 3, 1, 6], [1, 6, 1, 9], [1,1, 1,2]]

[list(np.array(a[i])*np.array(a[j])) for i in range(len(a)) for j in range(len(a)) if i!=j]

#expand version
# out = []
# for i in range(len(a)):
#     for j in range(len(a)):
#         if i!=j:
#             out.append(list(np.array(a[i])*np.array(a[j])))
```

output:

```
[[2, 18, 1, 54],
 [2, 3, 1, 12],
 [2, 18, 1, 54],
 [1, 6, 1, 18],
 [2, 3, 1, 12],
 [1, 6, 1, 18]]
```

In this answer I use `numpy.array` and `*` like below: *(numpy do this for you)*

```
np.array([2, 3, 1, 6]) * np.array([1, 6, 1, 9])
# [2*1, 3*6, 1*1, 6*9]
```

Comment: I haven't learnt numpy before. What does it do?

Comment: @chicken `numpy`is library with many function, for this purpose you want iterator on your two list and each element * each element you can define it yourself or use `numpy` that do for you.

Comment: This is not the best way to use numpy

Comment: @MadPhysicist thanks a lot for your advices, I'm here for learning. can you explain why numpy is not best?

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.permutations`.

```
from itertools import permutations

a = [[2, 3, 1, 6], [1, 6, 1, 9], [1, 1, 1,2]]

b = []
for l1, l2 in permutations(a, 2):
    b.append([i*j for i, j in zip(l1, l2)])

# OR with comprehension

b = [[i*j for i, j in zip(l1, l2)] for l1, l2 in permutations(a, 2)]
```

Output:

```
>>> b
[[2, 18, 1, 54],
 [2, 3, 1, 12],
 [2, 18, 1, 54],
 [1, 6, 1, 18],
 [2, 3, 1, 12],
 [1, 6, 1, 18]]
```

Comment: and `itertools` like `numpy`  is library

Comment: Not bad but the OP said 'I am still pretty new with python', so use `numpy` is not recommended.

Comment: `itertools` comes with Python, `numpy` not except if you use Anaconda (not Miniconda)

Comment: OK but your answer is not good for OP that new in python!!! `permutation`, `zip`

Comment: it's better instead of this line `Use itertools.permutations(standard library instead of numpy)` you explain `zip` for new python programmer

Answer (score 1):

You can use zip for multiplying and a `for` loop for accessing the elements.

```py
a = [[2, 3, 1, 6], [1, 6, 1, 9], [1,1, 1,2]]
b = a

result = []

for i in a:
    for j in b:
        if(j!=i):
            k = [n1 * n2 for n1,n2 in zip(i, j)] 
            result.append(k) 
          
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can speed up the computation by using numpy and realizing that `a * b == b * a`.

First convert `a` to a numpy array:

```
a = np.array(a)
```

The output will be a 3D array:

```
output = np.empty((a.shape[0], a.shape[0] - 1, a.shape[1]), dtype=a.dtype)
```

Now get the indices in `a` that you want to multiply together:

```
r, c = np.triu_indices(a.shape[0], k=1)
```

Now do the multiplication:

```
output[r, c - 1] = a[r] * a[c]
```

The lower half of the matrix is just a copy of the upper, no need to multiply:

```
output[c, r] = output[r, c - 1]
```

This solution is vectorized, which means that all of the loops have been taken out of the python layer, and moved to a fast C implementation under the hood. You can see this with the operation `a[r] * a[c]`, which performs all of your multiplications in a single line. The advantage of using vectorized operations is that even when your dataset becomes very large, the operations run in a reasonable amount of time.